# «Пыль от топота» — это словосочетание?

Tags: синтаксис, словосочетания

**От топота копыт пыль по полю летит.**
Предложение нужно разобрать на словосочетания.
Является ли сочетание слов "пыль от топота" словосочетанием? Утверждают, что правильно только "летит от топота". Нужно обоснование.

Answer (score 1):

В данном предложении ОТ ТОПОТА действительно зависит от глагола ЛЕТИТ: *летит (почему? по какой причине?) от топота копыт.*

Если изъять ПЫЛЬ ОТ ТОПОТА (КОПЫТ) из данного контекста и выбрать другой контекст, то ОТ ТОПОТА (КОПЫТ) может стать **несогласованным определением** и будет зависеть от слова ПЫЛЬ: *надо убрать ПЫЛЬ (какую?) ОТ ТОПОТА (КОПЫТ)*. К глаголу УБРАТЬ сочетание ОТ ТОПОТА уже не относится.

Comment: Словосочетание должно подходить под схему  _____от чего?_____. Почему  нельзя использовать ПЫЛЬ ' от чего?' ОТ ТОПОТА, так же как и ЛЕТИТ ' от чего?' ОТ ТОПОТА? Я не понимаю.

Comment: ОТ ТОПОТА находится ВПЕРЕДИ глагола - сказуемого, это остоятельство, зависит от глагола (летит почему? отчего? как?). Если бы ОТ ТОПОТА стояло после слова ПЫЛЬ, тогда сочетание зависело бы от слова ПЫЛЬ - пыль (какая? от чего?) ОТ ТОПОТА. Сравните: У ДОРОГИ ДОМ. - ДОМ У ДОРОГИ.

Comment: Согласен с вами!

Answer (score 0):

> Предложение "От топота копыт пыль по полю летит" нужно разобрать на
> словосочетания. Является ли сочетание слов "пыль от топота"
> словосочетанием?

На мой взгляд — **является**.

Особенно наглядно это можно увидеть при перестановке слов в рассматриваемом предложении:

*По полю летит **пыль (какая?) от топота** копыт.*

Comment: Совершенно согласна, что в варианте с предложенной вами перестановкой слов появляется словосочетание ПЫЛЬ ОТ ТОПОТА. Но если перестановку не делать, ОТ ТОПОТА будет  зависеть от глагола ЛЕТИТ.